# Couldn't find User without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am new to rails and I have just started making a facebook clone and I am starting out with the friends function, however I am getting the error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show  Couldn't find User without an ID any help would be much appreciated

here is a picture of the error [image]

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_user

def show
    
end

def friend
    current_user.sent_follow_request_to(@user)
    redirect_to root_path
end

def unfriend
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    @user.unfollow(current_user)
    redirect_to root_path
end

def accept
    current_user.accept_follow_request_of(@user)
    current_user.send_follow_request_to(@user)
    @user.accept_follow_request_of(current_user)
    redirect_to root_path
end

def decline
    current_user.decline_follow_request_of(@user)
    redirect_to root_path
end

def cancel
    current_user.remove_follow_request_for(@user)
    redirect_to root_path
end

private

def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

end


end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

followability

def unfollow(user)
followerable_relationships.where(followable_id: user.id).destroy_all
end

end
```

routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users



 post 'users/:id/unfriend', to: 'users#unfriend', as: 'unfriend'
 post 'users/:id/friend', to: 'users#friend', as: 'follow'
 post 'users/:id/accept', to: 'users#accept', as: 'accept'
 post 'users/:id/decline', to: 'users#decline', as: 'decline'
 post 'users/:id/cancel', to: 'users#cancel', as: 'cancel'

 get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'users'

 resources :users

 root 'users#show'
 # Define your application routes per the DSL in 
 https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

 # Defines the root path route ("/")
 # root "articles#index"
 end
```

Comment: What is in `params[:id]`. I bet it's `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your [root route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root):

```
root 'users#show'
```

You've defined your root web page, that is what will show up when the user requests `/`, as when they go to `http://localhost:3000`. It's set to the page which shows a specific user. This requires a User ID to do its job. But there is no ID provided.

Pick something else for your root page. `users#index` for example. Or your registration and sign on page. See [the Devise docs](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/#getting-started) for setting that up.

Comment: thx, I added a pages controller with a home action and put current_user.username in the home view and changed my root to 'pages#home'